# Escape special characters while sourcing a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with the following contents -

```
a=hello
b='hi'
c=['hi', 'hello']
```

I want to source the contents of the file. But I get the following error -

`-bash: hello]: command not found`

How do I escape the special characters?

Comment: Just double quote them `c="['hi', 'hello']"` or single quote it as per your need. `c='['hi', 'hello']'`

Comment: I don't want to change the way arrays are written. Is there a way to escape those characters while sourcing the file?

Comment: Proper Bash syntax would be `c=('hi' 'hello')` if that's what you want.  You could painfully replace into a temporary file and source that, but this sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Version 1: No bash arrays

I think what you are looking for is the `declare` command.  For example, with your definitions in the file `file`:

```
$ cat file
a=hello
b='hi'
c=['hi', 'hello']
```

Let's run `declare` on each line of your file:

```
$ while read -r line; do declare "$line"; done <file
```

We can verify that the definitions were successful and that the environment variables were created by using the `-p` option:

```
$ declare -p a b c
declare -- a="hello"
declare -- b="'hi'"
declare -- c="['hi', 'hello']"
```

Or, using them in an echo statement:

```
$ echo "a=$a b=$b c=$c"
a=hello b='hi' c=['hi', 'hello']
```

Unlike sourcing, `declare` does not execute your file.  This makes it much safer to use.

Using this approach, the `c` variable is a string.

#### Version  2: bash arrays

This code attempts to parse your assignments and make variables into arrays were appropriate:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
  case "$line" in
      *[*)
          line=${line/[/(}
          line=${line/]/)}
          line=${line//,/ }
          declare -a "$line"
          ;;
      *)
          declare "$line"
          ;;
  esac
done <file
```

After this code is run, `c` is an actual bash array:

```
$ declare -p a b c
declare -- a="hello"
declare -- b="'hi'"
declare -a c='([0]="hi" [1]="hello")'
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage is incorrect. If it is that you want to initialize c with an array,
you can do it as follows.

```
cat test
a=hello
b='hi'
c= ('hi' 'hello')
```

source test will not give any error.
you can use the bellow command to see the content of c

```
 echo ${c[@]}
```

which gives the below output

```
 hi hello
```